# Unable to parse stringified array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, stringify

I have this example code:

```
let testData= [{name:'Joshua',age:22,option:"[{value:'test'}]"},{name:'Ali',age:200,option:"[{value:'test2'}]"}]

let parsedData=JSON.parse(testData[0].option);
console.log(parsedData);
```

Testing my code using this site: https://es6console.com/

It seems that I'm unable to parse & log the data at all.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `option` is invalid JSON as `value` needs to be quoted... `'[{"value":"test"}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `option` string is not following the JSON specs: in JSON every key and string value needs to be enclosed in *double* quotes. So this would work:

```js
let testData= [{
    name: 'Joshua',
    age: 22,
    option: '[{"value": "test"}]'
}, {
    name: 'Ali',
    age: 200,
    option: '[{"value": "test2"}]'
}];

let parsedData = JSON.parse(testData[0].option);
console.log(parsedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that JSON object's fields should be wrapped in double-quotes. 
E.g.

```
let testData = [{name:'Joshua',age:22,option:`[{"value":'test'}]`},{name:'Ali',age:200,option:`[{"value":'test2'}]`}]
```